# mysqli_prepare statement failing

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a insert query, which i have been using throughout my website. works perfectly, i have used the came query in this webpage but have added validations to the query.
I have now ran my query, and I'm receiving the following error:

```
Undefined variable: run_query
```

$run_query is the name of my mysqli_prepare variable. I am extremely confused as i don't understand why i am receiving this error, which seems to be stopping my entire query from working.

```
$add_product_errors = array();  
if (isset($_POST['Submit_addon'])) {             
    $item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $desc = $_POST['desc'];
    $price = $_POST['price'];
    // price validate - must be decimal(float)
    if (empty($_POST['price']) || !filter_var($_POST['price'], FILTER_VALIDATE_FLOAT) || ($_POST['price'] <= 0)) {
        $add_product_errors['price'] = "Please enter a product price";
    }
    // item name validate
    if (empty($_POST['item_name'])) {
        $add_product_errors['item_name'] = "Please enter a name";
    }
    // item name description
    if (empty($_POST['desc'])) {
        $add_product_errors['desc'] = "Please enter a product description";
    }
    //add to database
    //if (empty($add_product_errors)) {
    $query = "INSERT INTO Product (Product_Name,Product_Desc,Product_Price) VALUES (?,?,?) 
                ON DUPLICATE KEY 
                  UPDATE
                  Product_Name = VALUES(Product_Name)
                  ,Product_Desc = VALUES(Product_Desc)
                  ,Product_Price = VALUES(Product_Price)"; 
    $run_query = mysqli_prepare($dbc, $query);
    //debugging
    if (!$run_query) echo mysqli_stmt_error($run_query);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($run_query, 'sss', $item_name, $desc, $price);
    $execute = mysqli_stmt_execute($run_query);
    $item_name = strip_tags($_POST['item_name']);
    $desc = strip_tags($_POST['desc']);
    //100 - changes the way the decimal displays in database
    $price = strip_tags($_POST['price'] * 100);
    //execute the query
    if ($execute) {
        echo "<script> alert('Addrrss Saved')</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<b>Oops! we have an issue </b>";
    }
}
mysqli_stmt_close($run_query);
```

Could somebody shread some light on why my mysql_prepare would fail.

Comment: just to note, you are validating your "price" as a float, but later you are binding it in your sql statement as a string.

Answer (score 3):

Put the line:

```
mysqli_stmt_close($run_query);
```

inside the `if` block. Otherwise you execute that line when the form hasn't been posted and you didn't do the `$run_query` assignment.

Also, when `if (!$run_query)` succeeds and you print the error, you should exit the script. Otherwise, you'll just fall through to the rest of the code that tries to perform the query, even though preparing it failed. And you can't call `mysqli_stmt_error()` when the argument isn't a statement, you need to call `mysqli_error()`. Change that line to:

```
if (!$run_query) {
    die(mysqli_error($dbc));
}
```

Comment: thanks, that sorted the error. I know must work out why it is not working